# How do I run opendistro elasticsearch in docker on HTTP

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I'm trying to run the docker image of the AWS opendistro elasticsearch on my laptop for tesing

https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/install/docker/

When I run it, it expects an HTTPS connection. How do I run it on HTTP?

I'm using this command to run:

`docker run -d --name elasticsearch-od -p 9200:9200 -p 9600:9600 -e "discovery.type=single-node"`

Answer (score 1):

in your docker-compose.yml you need change this parametres:

environment:
ELASTICSEARCH_URL: https://odfe-node1:9200
ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: https://odfe-node1:9200

For this:

environment:
ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://odfe-node1:9200
ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://odfe-node1:9200

And after in your file config for elasticsearch put this:

https-enabled = false

Try and enjoy ;)

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using docker compose, only docker.